iOS Live activity banner not appearing on devices without Dynamic Island
I am developing live activity which will show only the remaining time of parking which is fixed. It should show the timer on both locked and unlocked screen.
As per the Apple documentation:

On devices that don’t support the Dynamic Island, the system uses the
Lock Screen presentation of your Live Activity as a banner that
briefly overlays the Home Screen or another app. This overlay only
happens when you alert people about an update to your Live Activity
with an alert configuration.

The system displays the Lock Screen presentation as a banner for a Live Activity update if:

The device is unlocked and its app isn’t in use

You pass an AlertConfiguration to the update(_:alertConfiguration:)
function


I went through their demo video and passed alert configuration as following:
struct ParkWidgetAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
    
    var startDate: Date
    var endDate: Date

    // 'ContentState' represents the dynamic content of the Live Activity.
    public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
        // Dynamic stateful properties about your activity go here!
        var parkingTimer: ClosedRange<Date>
    }
}

func startLiveActivity() {

    let now = Date.now
    let future = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minutes, to: now)!
    let dateRange = now...future

    // (1) Fixed Attributes
    let activityAttributes = ParkWidgetAttributes(startDate: now, endDate: future)

    // (2) Content State
    let initialContentState = ParkWidgetAttributes.ContentState(parkingTimer: dateRange)

    let activityContent = ActivityContent(
        state: initialContentState,
        staleDate: future
    )

    do {
        let activity = try Activity.request(attributes: activityAttributes,
                                 content: activityContent)
        
        // Pass an AlertConfiguration to the update(_:alertConfiguration:) function
        Task {
            let alertConfig = AlertConfiguration(
                title: "Alert title",
                body: "Alert body",
                sound: .default
            )
            await activity.update(activityContent, alertConfiguration: alertConfig)
        }

    } catch (let error) {
        print("Error requesting Parking Live Activity \(error.localizedDescription).")
    }
}

Using above implementation, the live activity appears on lock screen for both the devices (with and without Dynamic Island). But for unlocked screen, it only appears on device with Dynamic Island.

Have you come up with a solution yet?

Yes, I have came to the conclusion. It will not shown automatically but we will have to send an update (live activity push notification) with an alert configuration, then the system displays the Lock Screen presentation as a banner at the top of the screen to let them know about the updated Live Activity.
